# Taking the limit in Poisson summation formula as the step size tends to zero

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

I'm working on the latter half of Exercise 9.11 from Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis* about the Poisson summation formula. Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be positive numbers such that $\alpha\beta = 2\pi$. For a sufficiently "nice" function $f$ on the real line,
$$ \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} f(k\beta) = \frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \hat{f}(n\alpha), \tag{1} $$
where $\hat{f}$ is the (scaled) Fourier transform of $f$:
$$ \hat{f}(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t)e^{-ixt} \:dt. $$
The problem is to describe what the Poisson summation formula entails by allowing $\alpha$ to approach $0$. I have a vague sense that the left side of (1) will tend to $f(0)$ and the right will tend to the scaled integral
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat{f}(x) \:dx, $$
provided $f$ or $\hat{f}$ are suitably nice, but I'm having a difficult time coming up with a rigorous description.

For the right side of (1), my guess comes from pulling the limit through the integral in the end:
$$ \lim_{\alpha\to 0} \frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \hat{f}(n\alpha) = \lim_{\alpha\to 0} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat{f}(n\alpha)\chi_{[n\alpha,(n+1)\alpha)}(x) \:dx, $$
but I'm not sure what sensible conditions to put on $f$ to do so. Saying the family of integrands is dominated seems too artificial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is correct. The expression
$$\alpha \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \hat{f}(n\alpha)$$
is like Riemann sum for $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \hat f(\xi)\,d\xi$, except, of course, Riemann sums are normally considered on a finite interval. Dealing within this kind of sum is a bit annoying, so let's focus on the left hand side of $(1)$ instead. Suppose there are constants $C$ and $p>1$ such that
$$
|f(x)|\le C|x|^{-p}
$$
for large $x$. This isn't a super strong assumption; reasonable integrable functions tend to decay like that. 
As $\beta\to\infty$, we get
$$
\left| \sum_{k\ne 0} f(k\beta) \right| \le \beta^{-p}\sum_{k\ne 0}|k|^{-p} \to 0
$$
so the left hand side of $(1)$ indeed converges to $f(0)$.

Of course, so does the right hand side since they are equal. At this point I'm inclined to cop out by saying: suppose also that $\hat f$ is integrable; then the Fourier inversion formula holds.
$$
f(0) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty\hat f(\xi)\,d\xi
$$ 
So that's the proof that 
$$\alpha \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \hat{f}(n\alpha)\to \int_{-\infty}^\infty \hat f(\xi)\,d\xi\tag2$$
as $\alpha\to 0 $.

---

Proving $(2)$ directly seems awkward. 
If $f$ is integrable, then $\hat f$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. 
which tells us that $\alpha \hat f(n\alpha)$ is uniformly close to $\int_{n\alpha}^{(n+1)\alpha}\hat f(\xi)\,d\xi$. Unfortunately, a uniform bound isn't much good with infinitely many terms. We need something like 
$$\left|\alpha \hat f(n\alpha) - \int_{n\alpha}^{(n+1)\alpha}\hat f(\xi)\,d\xi\right| < \frac{C(\alpha)}{n^p} \tag3$$
with $p>1$, and $C(\alpha)\to 0$ as $\alpha\to 0$; this way the errors add up to a small quantity. By the mean value theorem the left hand side of $(3)$ is bounded by $\alpha^2 \sup_{[n\alpha, (n+1)\alpha]}|\hat f'|$ so if we have $|\hat f'|\le C/|x|^p$ for some $1<p<2$, then $(2)$ follows. This is a relatively strong assumption compared to the first part of this post.

Comment: I used your decay condition idea to prove (2) under different circumstances. I posted it below your answer if you are curious

Comment: That's a nice approach.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have an extension to Michelle's answer above that proves (2) under different restrictions on $\hat{f}$. Suppose the principal value integral of $\hat{f}$ exists, that is, suppose
$$
\lim_{A\to\infty} \int_{-A}^{A} \hat{f}(x) \:dx < \infty,
$$
call this limit $I$, and suppose there exist constants $B$ and $p$, where $B<\infty$ and $p>1$, such that
$$
\lvert x^{p}\hat{f}(x)\rvert \leq B
$$
for every (sufficiently large) real number $x$. Let $\epsilon$ be a positive number, and let $A$ be a positive number such that
$$
\Bigl\lvert I - \int_{-A}^{A} \hat{f}(x) \:dx\Bigr\rvert < \epsilon, \quad
\int_{A}^{\infty} Bx^{-p} \:dx < \epsilon.
$$
Let $\alpha$ be a positive number such that $A/\alpha$ is an integer $K$, but small enough so that $\alpha\hat{f}(0)<\epsilon$ and
$$
\Bigl\lvert \int_{-A}^{A} \hat{f}(x) \:dx + \alpha\hat{f}(0) - \sum_{-K}^{K} \alpha \hat{f}(n\alpha)\Bigr\rvert < \epsilon.
$$
The possibility of this inequality follows from the assumption that $\hat{f}$ is Riemann integrable on $[-A,A]$. The Riemann sum takes the right endpoints as approximations on $[0,A]$ and left endpoints as approximations on $[-A,0]$.

The decay condition entails
$$
\Bigl\lvert \sum_{K+1}^{\infty} \alpha\hat{f}(n\alpha)\Bigr\rvert
 \leq \sum_{K+1}^{\infty} \alpha B(n\alpha)^{-p} \leq \int_{A}^{\infty} Bx^{-p} \:dx
 < \epsilon,
$$
since the middle expression is an infinite lower Riemann sum of the right integral using right endpoints, and an analogous statement holds for the lower tail of the series $\sum \alpha\hat{f}(n\alpha)$. Therefore,
$$
\Bigl\lvert I - \sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} \alpha\hat{f}(n\alpha)\Bigr\rvert \leq 5\epsilon.
$$
The crux of the argument is to use the decay to obtain a *lower* approximation for the tails.